# Errors compling command-line apps in iOS

Tags: ios, gcc, command-line, compilation, cydia

I've installed the GNU C Compiler, libgcc (from the Radare repository), automake, make, and probably some other packages that I've forgot about in an attempt to compile some common command-line apps on my fourth-generation iPod Touch. My success rate has been zero.

Regardless of what I try to build, I usually get an error along the lines of "C compiler cannot create executables," as in the excerpt below:

```
checking build system type... arm-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... arm-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... arm-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/root/htop-2.0.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

You can review the [config.log](https://pastebin.com/u96S7ycZ) here. I believe that the problem has to do with "ld: library not found for -lSystem," but I'm not entirely sure how to resolve that. I get the same or similar errors no matter what I try to compile.